# How do I express the MySql function `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT column)` in Arel?

Tags: mysql, arel

I can use

```
Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('GROUP_CONCAT', [an_arel_table[:a_column]])
```

to generate

```
GROUP_CONCAT(a_column)
```

in my `SELECT` statement. But how do I add the `DISTINCT` option?

```
Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('GROUP_CONCAT', ['DISTINCT', an_arel_table[:a_column]])
```

yields

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT, a_column)
```

which is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but the following works.

`Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation` provides a mechanism for generating a sequence `X DISTINCT Y`. By setting `X` to blank (`Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('')`), we end up with `DISTINCT Y`.

```
Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('GROUP_CONCAT', [
  Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('DISTINCT',
        Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new(''),
        an_arel_table[:a_column]])])
```

Later versions of Arel (beyond Rails 4.2) support `UnaryOperation` which *may* allow expressing the `DISTINCT` modifier as `Arel::Nodes::UnaryOperation.new('DISTINCT', an_arel_table[:a_column])`. (UNTESTED)